# Broadcasting messages to all web workers in Clojure

Tags: clojure, websocket

I'm writing a Clojure application that uses websockets to communicate with clients. The server sometimes acts as a sort of hub, getting a message from one client and that triggering sending a message to another client. If I have only one web server that's fine, but if I have two I run into trouble as clients might be connected to different servers.

I think the best way to deal with this would be for a web server to broadcast the message received to the other ones so all of them can react and notify the appropriate client. How can I do this? Any libraries that can help?

If it matters, I'm planning on hosting this in Heroku at first but I always want to leave the door open for self hosting.

Comment: Essentially you are asking "How do I send a message from one server to other servers?" Well, in Clojure you could use something like Aleph in combination with Transit or Fressian which is just one of many ways of solving this problem. Is this the kind of answer you are looking for? I'd prefer if you made your question a bit more specific.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin no, my question is a bit more complex than that. How do servers find each other when I start and stop them for example?

Comment: There is a variety of architectural constructs and technologies that could be used per Clojure to solve this problem. Every possible answer would be an implementation consisting of several hundreds of lines of code. I think you should ask your question with a more concrete problem.